# While loop not working for c programming

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements, break

I am trying to get the program to allow the user to enter a currency they want to change the total cost to. when the user does enter a wrong input and then is prompted to enter again a correct currency, when they do enter a correct currency the while loop is not breaking. It keeps asking the user again to enter a correct currency.

```
Please enter the number of gallons of gasoline: 7

7.0 gallons of gasoline produces..
7.0 gallons of gasoline requires.. 
7.0 gallons of gasoline costs..

Choose a currency you want to see your total cost in (Euro, Pound, or Yen): eurooo

You need choose one of these currencies (Euro, Pound, or Yen). Please enter one: Euro

You need choose one of these currencies (Euro, Pound, or Yen). Please enter one: Euro

You need choose one of these currencies (Euro, Pound, or Yen). Please enter one:
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

float gas_gallons;
float cost_today_gallons;
int main()
{
    char input;
    printf("\nPlease enter the number of gallons of gasoline: ");
    scanf(" %c", &input);
    getchar();

    while (!isdigit(input))
    {
        printf("\nYou need to enter a digit. Please enter the number of gallons of gasoline: ");
        scanf("%c", &input);
        }

    if (isdigit(input))
    {
        gas_gallons = input - '0';

        float carbon_dioxide_pounds = gas_gallons * 19.64;
        printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline produces approximately %f pounds of carbon dioxide.", gas_gallons, carbon_dioxide_pounds );

        float barrels_crude_oil = gas_gallons/19.0;
        printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline requires %f barrels of crude oil.", gas_gallons, barrels_crude_oil);

        cost_today_gallons = gas_gallons*2.738;
        printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline costs a total average of %f US dollars today.", gas_gallons, cost_today_gallons);
        }

    char currency[100];
    printf("\nChoose a currency you want to see your total cost in (Euro, Pound, or Yen): ");
    scanf("%s", &currency);
    getchar();

    char *str1 = "Yen";
    char *str2 = "Euro";
    char *str3 = "Pound";

    while ((strcmp(currency, str1) != 0) || (strcmp(currency, str2) != 0) || (strcmp(currency, str3) != 0))
    {
        printf("\nYou need choose one of these currencies (Euro, Pound or Yen). Please enter one: ");
        scanf("%s", &currency);
    }

    if ((strcmp(currency, str1) == 0))
    {
        float yen_total_cost = cost_today_gallons*123.07;
        printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline costs a total average of %f Japenese Yens today.", gas_gallons, yen_total_cost);
    }
    if (strcmp(currency, str2) == 0)
    {
        float euro_total_cost = cost_today_gallons*0.92;
        printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline costs a total average of %f Euros today.", gas_gallons, euro_total_cost);
    }
    if (strcmp(currency, str3) == 0)
    {
        float pound_total_cost = cost_today_gallons*0.65;
        printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline costs a total average of %f British Pounds today.", gas_gallons, pound_total_cost);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Last time I've checked `while` was ok

Answer (score 2):

In this line
`while ((strcmp(currency, str1) != 0) || (strcmp(currency, str2) != 0) || (strcmp(currency, str3) != 0))`

you're telling your code to loop until `currency` is equal to `str1` **and** `str2` **and** `str3` which will never happen.

You need to change it to
`while ((strcmp(currency, str1) != 0) && (strcmp(currency, str2) != 0) && (strcmp(currency, str3) != 0))`

Answer (score 0):

scanf also adds the `\n` at the end. You'll need to either chop that off, or add it to the strings you're comparing to. Alternatively, if you don't care about someone entering something like "European money" instead of "Euro", you can use strncmp() instead of strcmp().

Note though that your code is vulnerable to a buffer overflow if someone enters more than 98 characters (after adding the `\n` and `\0`, you'll be at byte 101). To ensure that doesn't cause a problem,  you should use 'scanf("%99s")' instead, which will chop off the string after the 99th character (or, alternatively, use a different input function).

Answer (score 0):

You're using OR operators in your while statement when you should be using an AND. Whatever valid currency selected will fail 2 of the conditions so you're stuck in a loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works now and I understand why it was failing to break the loop.

Comment: No problem, seen that logical error so many times over the years, tripped myself up with it as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are sevreal issues.

This condition is wrong

```
while ((strcmp(currency, str1) != 0) || (strcmp(currency, str2) != 0) || strcmp(currency, str3) != 0))
```

Replaced by:

```
while ((strcmp(currency, str1) != 0) && (strcmp(currency, str2) != 0) && strcmp(currency, str3) != 0))
```

I let you find out the reason as an exercice.

Your usage of `scanf` is overly complicated, you probably want this:

```
float gas_gallons;
float cost_today_gallons;
int main()
{
    printf("\nPlease enter the number of gallons of gasoline: ");
    scanf("%f", &gas_gallons);

    float carbon_dioxide_pounds = gas_gallons * 19.64;
    printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline produces approximately %f pounds of carbon dioxide.", gas_gallons, carbon_dioxide_pounds );

    float barrels_crude_oil = gas_gallons/19.0;
    printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline requires %f barrels of crude oil.", gas_gallons, barrels_crude_oil);

    cost_today_gallons = gas_gallons*2.738;
    printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline costs a total average of %f US dollars today.", gas_gallons, cost_today_gallons);


    char currency[100];
    printf("\nChoose a currency you want to see your total cost in (Euro, Pound, or Yen): ");
    scanf("%s", currency);

    char *str1 = "Yen";
    char *str2 = "Euro";
    char *str3 = "Pound";

    while ((strcmp(currency, str1) != 0) && (strcmp(currency, str2) != 0) && (strcmp(currency, str3) != 0))
    {
        printf("\nYou need choose one of these currencies (Euro, Pound or Yen). Please enter one: ");
        scanf("%s", &currency);
    }

    if ((strcmp(currency, str1) == 0))
    {
        float yen_total_cost = cost_today_gallons*123.07;
        printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline costs a total average of %f Japenese Yens today.", gas_gallons, yen_total_cost);
    }
    if (strcmp(currency, str2) == 0)
    {
        float euro_total_cost = cost_today_gallons*0.92;
        printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline costs a total average of %f Euros today.", gas_gallons, euro_total_cost);
    }
    if (strcmp(currency, str3) == 0)
    {
        float pound_total_cost = cost_today_gallons*0.65;
        printf("\n%.2f gallons of gasoline costs a total average of %f British Pounds today.", gas_gallons, pound_total_cost);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Bonus: the choice of the variable names `str1`to `str3` is poor. Why not choose names as `strEuro`, `strYen`, `strPound` ?